# On creating a continuously moving, randomly generated, "3d" starfield

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS by working on a small space game on the HTML canvas. I'm trying to create a 3D starfield from a randomly generated array of stars. 
I have an array of 12 stars randomly generated from the elements of a larger star array containing 34 stars. When one star leaves the boundaries of the screen I want to remove it from the smaller array and replace it with another randomly generated element from the larger star array, all while keeping it continuously moving in the animate function. I've tried several approaches but I just can't seem to find the right syntax...or possibly the right way of looking at the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code follows below:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  width="1024" height="768">
</canvas> 

<script>
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");        

    var starsArray; 
    var randStarsArray;        
    var numStars = 12;  


    // Star object
    var Star = function(x, y, width, height, velX, velY) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }   

    // Create individual stars
    var star1 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(135*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(135*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 6);     
    var star2 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (135 * Math.cos(135*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (135 * Math.sin(135*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 6);     
    var star3 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(320*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(320*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -6);
    var star4 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(310*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(310*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -6);     
    var star5 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(270*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(270*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 0, -6);     
    var star6 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(0*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(0*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, 0);      
    var star7 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(90*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(90*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 0, 6);        
    var star8 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(180*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(180*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 0);     
    var star9 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(270*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(270*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 0, -6);     
    var star10 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(0*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(0*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, 0);     
    var star11 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(90*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(90*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 0, 6);       
    var star12 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(60*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(60*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 3, 6);       
    var star13 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(45*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(45*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, 6);       
    var star14 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(210*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(210*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, -3);       
    var star15 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(225*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(225*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, -6);       
    var star16 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(150*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(150*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 3);        
    var star17 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(150*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(150*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 3);        
    var star18 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(30*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, 3);       
    var star19 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(180*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(180*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 0);        
    var star20 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(330*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(330*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -3);        
    var star21 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(300*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(300*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 3, -6);        
    var star22 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (150 * Math.cos(240*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (150 * Math.sin(240*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -3, -6);       
    var star23 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(240*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(240*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -3, -6);       
    var star24 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(330*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(330*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -3);        
    var star25 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(30*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, 3);       
    var star26 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (100 * Math.cos(120*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (100 * Math.sin(120*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -3, 6);        
    var star27 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(135*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(135*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, 6);        
    var star28 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(120*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(120*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -3, 6);        
    var star29 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (200 * Math.cos(210*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (200 * Math.sin(210*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, -3);
    var star30 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(300*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(300*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 3, -6);        
    var star31 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (25 * Math.cos(45*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (25 * Math.sin(45*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -6);
    var star32 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (25 * Math.cos(225*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (25 * Math.sin(225*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, -6, -6);
    var star33 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (250 * Math.cos(60*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (250 * Math.sin(60*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 3, 6);
    var star34 = new Star(myCanvas.width/2 + (25 * Math.cos(315*Math.PI/180)), myCanvas.height/2 + (25 * Math.sin(315*Math.PI/180)), 5, 5, 6, -6);

    // Game initialization
    function init() {
        startGame();
    }

    // Start game
    function startGame(){

        // Game variables
        starsArray = new Array(); 
        randStarsArray = new Array();               

        // Push stars onto array
        starsArray.push(star1);
        starsArray.push(star2);
        starsArray.push(star3);
        starsArray.push(star4);
        starsArray.push(star5);
        starsArray.push(star6);
        starsArray.push(star7);
        starsArray.push(star8);
        starsArray.push(star9);
        starsArray.push(star10);
        starsArray.push(star11);
        starsArray.push(star12);
        starsArray.push(star13);
        starsArray.push(star14);
        starsArray.push(star15);
        starsArray.push(star16);
        starsArray.push(star17);
        starsArray.push(star18);
        starsArray.push(star19);
        starsArray.push(star20);
        starsArray.push(star21);
        starsArray.push(star22);
        starsArray.push(star23);
        starsArray.push(star24);
        starsArray.push(star25);
        starsArray.push(star26);
        starsArray.push(star27);
        starsArray.push(star28);
        starsArray.push(star29);
        starsArray.push(star30);
        starsArray.push(star31);
        starsArray.push(star32);
        starsArray.push(star33);
        starsArray.push(star34);            


        for(i = 0; i < numStars; i++){              
            randStarsArray[i] = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)]; 
        }                       

        animate();
    }


    function changeStar(){      
        var index = randStarsArray.indexOf(tempStar);

        if (index > -1) {
            //randStarsArray[index] = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)];
            randStarsArray.splice(index, 1);
            randStarsArray.push(starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)]);                                
        }           
    }


    // Animation loop
    function animate(){

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height); 

        for(i = 0; i < numStars; i++){  
            var tempStar = randStarsArray[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"; // white stars            
            ctx.fillRect(randStarsArray[i].x, randStarsArray[i].y, randStarsArray[i].width, randStarsArray[i].height);              

            tempStar.x += tempStar.velX;
            tempStar.y += tempStar.velY;                                


            if(tempStar.x + tempStar.width < 0 || tempStar.x > myCanvas.width || 
              tempStar.y + tempStar.height < 0 || tempStar.y > myCanvas.height){

                changeStar();
            }

        }


        setTimeout(animate, 33);
    }


    init();


</script>
```

Comment: `tempStar` is out of scope in the function `changeStar`. It seems you can just pass it as an argument: call it as `changeStar(tempStar);`, declare the function as `function changeStar(tempStar){`…`}`.

Comment: I actually woke up with that thought, that it was not in scope. But even so, i can only get it to run a few iterations, replacing stars, and then it just ...stops. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Have you opened the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and received any error?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I just ran it again with the web console open. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var Canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = Canvas.getContext("2d");
    var starsArray;
    var randStarsArray;
    var numStars = 12;
    // Star object
    var Star = function(x, y, width, height, velX, velY) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    var M = [150, 135, 150, 150, 100, 150, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 150, 200, 150, 200, 200, 100, 100, 250, 100, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 100, 250, 250, 200, 250, 25, 25, 250, 25];
    var N = [135, 135, 320, 310, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 60, 45, 210, 225, 150, 150, 30, 180, 330, 300, 240, 240, 330, 30, 120, 135, 120, 210, 300, 45, 225, 60, 315];
    var Z = [-6, -6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0, -6, 0, 6, 0, 3, 6, -6, -6, -6, -6, 6, -6, 6, 3, -3, -3, 6, 6, -3, -3 - 6, -3, -6, 6, -6, 3, 6];
    var K = [6, 6, -6, -6, -6, 0, 6, 0, -6, 0, 6, 6, 6, -3, -6, 3, 3, 3, 0, -3, -6, -6, -6, -3, 3, 6, 6, 6, -3, -6, -6, -6, 6, -6];
    var star = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 34; i++) {
        star[i] = new Star(Canvas.width / 2 + (M[i] * Math.cos(N[i] * Math.PI / 180)), Canvas.height / 2 + (M[i] * Math.sin(N[i] * Math.PI / 180)), 5, 5, Z[i], K[i]);
    }
    // Game initialization
    function init() {
        startGame();
    }
    // Start game
    function startGame() {
        // Game variables
        starsArray = [];
        randStarsArray = [];

        // Push stars onto array
        // 这是所有的star
        for (var i = 0; i < star.length; i++) {
            starsArray.push(star[i])
        }
        // console.dir(starsArray);//所有的星星
        var randomArray = []; //渲染的 星星
        // 判断数据是否为12个数据
        while (randomArray.length < numStars) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 34);
            if (randomArray.indexOf(random) === -1) {
                randomArray.push(random);
            }
        }
        console.log(randomArray)

        for (var i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
            randStarsArray[i] = starsArray[randomArray[i]];
        }
        console.log(randStarsArray);
        animate();
    }

    // Animation loop
    function animate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
        for (i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
            var tempStar = randStarsArray[i];
            console.log(tempStar);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(55, 100, 0)"; // white stars
            ctx.fillRect(tempStar.x, tempStar.y, tempStar.width, tempStar.height);


            tempStar.x += tempStar.velX;
            tempStar.y += tempStar.velY;
            if (tempStar.x + tempStar.width < 0 || tempStar.x > Canvas.width ||
                tempStar.y + tempStar.height < 0 || tempStar.y > Canvas.height) {

                changeStar(tempStar);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(animate, 300);
    }



    function changeStar(tempStar) {
        var index = randStarsArray.indexOf(tempStar);
        if (index > -1) {
            //randStarsArray[index] = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)];
            randStarsArray.splice(index, 1);
            randStarsArray.push(starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)]);
        }
    }

    init();
    </script>`enter code here`
```

Comment: That is a nice refactor of the code, but you should probably explain in words what you did and what the OP did wrong.

Comment: That's a really neat refactoring, and it does work, but only for a few iterations.  After that it just stops replacing stars and the screen is blank. I'm not sure what I need to do to keep it continuously working. I know it's something simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.      EDIT: The console seems to be still showing output but nothing is being drawn to the screen after a few iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.  I appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, although I will refactor it along the lines that mingye.wei did when I have the time, because it looks nicer.  I was complicating the answer too much - figuring I had to remove/splice out the old star from the randomArray after it left the screen and then adding a new random star from the starsArray to randomArray. Turns out, all I needed to do was simply update tempStar's x, y, velX, and velY with a newly generated random star from 
starsarray. Now it runs continuously. :)   Code follows below:

// Animation loop
        function animate(){

```
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);            

        for(var i = 0; i < numStars; i++){  
            var tempStar = randomStarsArray[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"; // white stars            
            ctx.fillRect(tempStar.x, tempStar.y, tempStar.width, tempStar.height);              

            tempStar.x += tempStar.velX;
            tempStar.y += tempStar.velY;                                

            // When tempStar moves off the screen...
            if(tempStar.x + tempStar.width < 0 || tempStar.x > myCanvas.width || 
              tempStar.y + tempStar.height < 0 || tempStar.y > myCanvas.height){                  

                // ... replace it with a new random star from starsArray
                var renewStar = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)];
                tempStar.x = renewStar.x;
                tempStar.y = renewStar.y;
                tempStar.velX = renewStar.velX;
                tempStar.velY = renewStar.velY;                 
            }

        }


        setTimeout(animate, 33);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post the refactored code for a 3D continuous star field background for anyone who might be interested. Code follows:
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

```
    // star variables
    var starsArray; 
    var randomStarsArray;        
    var numStars = 14;  


    // Star object
    var Star = function(x, y, width, height, velX, velY) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
    }           

    // Variables for Star object creation
    // sD = distance of star from canvas center
    // sA = angle from center origin
    var sD = [150, 135, 150, 150, 100, 150, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 150, 200, 150, 200, 200, 100, 100, 250, 100, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 100, 250, 250, 200, 250, 25, 25, 250, 25];
    var sA = [135, 135, 320, 310, 270, 0, 90, 180, 270, 0, 90, 60, 45, 210, 225, 150, 150, 30, 180, 330, 300, 240, 240, 330, 30, 120, 135, 120, 210, 300, 45, 225, 60, 315];
    var sVX = [-6, -6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0, -6, 0, 6, 0, 3, 6, -6, -6, -6, -6, 6, -6, 6, 3, -3, -3, 6, 6, -3, -3 - 6, -3, -6, 6, -6, 3, 6];
    var sVY = [6, 6, -6, -6, -6, 0, 6, 0, -6, 0, 6, 6, 6, -3, -6, 3, 3, 3, 0, -3, -6, -6, -6, -3, 3, 6, 6, 6, -3, -6, -6, -6, 6, -6];


    // Game initialization
    function init(){

        // Game variables
        starsArray = []; 
        randomStarsArray = [];              

        // Push stars onto starsArray
        for (var i = 0; i < 34; i++) {  
            starsArray[i] = new Star(myCanvas.width / 2 + (sD[i] * Math.cos(sA[i] * Math.PI / 180)), myCanvas.height / 2 + (sD[i] * Math.sin(sA[i] * Math.PI / 180)), 5, 5, sVX[i], sVY[i]);
        }

        // Create a small array of random stars from starsArray to draw
        for(var i = 0; i < numStars; i++){              
            randomStarsArray[i] = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)];   
        }                       

        animate();
    }   


    // Animation loop
    function animate(){

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);            

        for(var i = 0; i < numStars; i++){  
            var tempStar = randomStarsArray[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"; // white stars            
            ctx.fillRect(tempStar.x, tempStar.y, tempStar.width, tempStar.height);              

            tempStar.x += tempStar.velX;
            tempStar.y += tempStar.velY;                                

            // When tempStar moves off the screen...
            if(tempStar.x + tempStar.width < 0 || tempStar.x > myCanvas.width || 
              tempStar.y + tempStar.height < 0 || tempStar.y > myCanvas.height){                  

                // ... replace it with a new random star from starsArray
                var renewStar = starsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 34)];
                tempStar.x = renewStar.x;
                tempStar.y = renewStar.y;
                tempStar.velX = renewStar.velX;
                tempStar.velY = renewStar.velY;                 
            }

        }

        // setTimeout is used for recursive calls to loop a function
        setTimeout(animate, 33);
    }


    init();
```